# Mimicking Günther Uecker's nail art

Tags: plotting, graphics, vector, generative-art

One of my favourite contemporary artists is Günther Uecker (born 13 March 1930 in Crivitz, Germany). He uses hammer and nails to create `VectorPlot`-like structures. We can see him here in action:

[image]

A view from above:

[image]

Many of his works are relief printed, creating raised images, which results in a 3D effect.

[image]

This reminded me a little of a `LineIntegralConvolutionPlot`:

```
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 ColorFunction -> "GrayTones",
 StreamMarkers -> "Drop",
 StreamPoints -> Coarse,
 StreamStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8],
 StreamColorFunction -> None]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, there are no nails included in `StreamMarkers`, and I also don't know how to produce the paper-like background. Probably some image-processing is required, but my knowledge of Mathematica's vast image-processing options is extremely limited.

[image]

**My Question**

How can we produce Uecker-structures with Mathematica - either the whitish printed variant or even an image like the second from above?

Comment: No time to try this now, but for the 3d one, maybe grab a obj file of a nail like this https://grabcad.com/library/din-1151-wire-nails-1, then plot your vector field, and rotate the meshes according to the arrows, then use MaterialShading to give the nails a metallic look.

Comment: @domen - please don't change the title of my question

Comment: @eldo, please read the [guide on asking the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): _"a title that clearly and succinctly summarizes your problem"_ Also: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) might be of use. "Hammer and nails" is not an informative title, sorry, and this is a community site where other people actually _can_ edit your questions.

Comment: https://flickr.com/photos/hobbified/2660381380/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just an idea about using **VectorPlot3D** with a custom nail marker:

```
nail[l : {a : {x_, y_, z_}, b : {u_, v_, w_}}, s_ : 1] := 
  Module[{p = 1/35, r = 1/9, q = 1/145},
   {Cylinder[{1.2 a, (1.2 a + p*b)/(1 + p)}, .07]
    , Tube[
       BSplineCurve[{1.2 a, (1.2 a + q*b)/(1 + q), (1.2 a + r*b)/(1 + r),  b}]
      , {.04, .025, .022, .01}]}];


vplot = VectorPlot3D[
  {Abs@Cos[x], Abs[Cos[x] Sin[y]], Abs@Sin[.2 z^2]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}
  , RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y + z < 4 && -.01 < x < .02]
  , RegionBoundaryStyle -> {LightGray, Opacity[.6]}
  , PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}
  , VectorPoints -> 21, VectorMarkers -> "Tube"
  , ViewPoint -> {-\[Infinity], 0, 0}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False
  , ImageSize -> Large, Lighting -> "ThreePoint"
  , PlotRangePadding -> 1, ClippingStyle -> None
  (* VectorStyle used together with MaterialShading slows down the rendering *)
  , VectorStyle -> {Gray, MaterialShading["Iron"] }];

(* Replace Tube with the nail function. There might be better ways to do this ... *)
 FullForm[vplot /. {Tube -> nail, Arrow -> Identity}][[1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
nail[x_, y_, fi1_, fi2_] := 
 GeometricTransformation[{Tube[{{x, y, -0.2}, {x, y, 1}}, 
    0.02], {LightGray, Tube[{{x, y, 1}, {x, y, 1.02}}, 0.1]}}, 
  RotationTransform[fi1, {Cos[fi2], Sin[fi2], 0}, {x, y, 0}]]
Graphics3D[{{Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {11, 0, 0}, {11, 11, 0}, {0, 11, 
      0}}]}, {Darker@Gray, CapForm["Butt"], 
   Table[nail[i, j, (i + j)/20*\[Pi]/4, (i + j)/20*2 \[Pi]], {i, 1, 
     10, 0.5}, {j, 1, 10, 0.5}]}, {Darker@Gray, CapForm["Butt"]}}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick thing I made using a rotated nail image:

```
img = Import[
   "https://pngimg.com/uploads/metal_nail/metal_nail_PNG17014.png"];
dim = {64, 128}; (* squishes the nail length in the first dimension*)
nail = ImageResize[ImageCrop[ImageRotate[img, 45 °]], dim];
vecplt = VectorPlot[{y + x, -2 x + y }, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
arrows = Cases[vecplt[[1]], Arrow[__], Infinity];
nails = ImageRotate[nail,
     ArcTan @@ -Subtract @@ (#[[1]])
     ] & /@ arrows;

Graphics[{
  MapThread[Inset[#1, #2[[1, 1]], dim/2, {1, 1}] &, {nails, arrows}]
  }]
```

[image: nails]